# c++ - Initialize objects inside vector declaration

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, stdvector

I'm writing a small command-line parsing library and you can describe options statically :

```
std::vector<Args::Descriptor> description{
    {UNKNOWN, 0,'h' , "help", Args::None, "print this help"}
};
```

where in my lib,

```
struct Descriptor {
  const uint option;
  const int  type;
  const char shortopt;
  const char* const longopt;
  const CheckArg check_arg; // Function pointer
  const char* help;
};
```

Then the Descriptor is used to initialize a class :

```
Option(const Descriptor *descriptor)
{ … }
```

Could I remove my Descriptor **structure** by initializing the Options **class** inside the vector ?

```
std::vector<Args::Option> options{
    {UNKNOWN, 0,'h' , "help", Args::None, "print this help"}
};
```

What signature should my Option constructor have ? Assuming the Descriptor class completely disappears from the code to simplify it.

Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work. `Option`'s constructor's argument is a pointer to a `Descriptor`. That `Descriptor` has to come from somewhere. You cannot initialize a pointer to a class with an instance of the class itself.

What you can do, though, is construct a vector of `Descriptor`s exactly how you are doing it now.

Then, initialize your `Option` vector with pointers to the individual values in your `Descriptor` vector.

This will work as long as, going forward, the first vector remains untouched.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing for now. But I was thinking I could change the Option constructor to smth like
Option(const uint option, const int  type, const char shortopt, const char* const longopt,const CheckArg check_arg, const char* help) {}

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Comment: Okay, didnt think it would be that easy… Thanks ^^